# How can I decode JWT token in android?

Tags: java, android, jwt

I have a [jwt](https://jwt.io/) token like this

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

How can I decode this so that I can get the payload like this

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true
}
```

I have used [this](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt)  library , but can't find a way to do what I want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74243959/7436566

Answer (score 81):

You should split JWT string using dot `.` as the delimeter.

If you pass the first two sections through a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) decoder, you'll get the following (formatting added for clarity):

#### Header:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

#### Body:

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true
}
```

---

### Code example:

```
public class JWTUtils {

    public static void decoded(String JWTEncoded) throws Exception {
        try {
            String[] split = JWTEncoded.split("\\.");
            Log.d("JWT_DECODED", "Header: " + getJson(split[0]));
            Log.d("JWT_DECODED", "Body: " + getJson(split[1]));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            //Error
        }
    }

    private static String getJson(String strEncoded) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(strEncoded, Base64.URL_SAFE);
        return new String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

#### Usage example:

```
JWTUtils.decoded("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ");
```

---

- Library reference:  https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt
- JWT test: https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 11):

I used a third-party library named JWTDecode.Android https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.Android. The documentation is reasonably good. From your question, The sub, name, etc are a part of the body and are called Claims. You could get them like this using the above library:

```
JWT parsedJWT = new JWT(jwtToken);
Claim subscriptionMetaData = parsedJWT.getClaim("name");
String parsedValue = subscriptionMetaData.asString();
```

Comment: @angryITguy it's not like it should be. Because other answers with different libraries are also correct. This library makes it easier.

Answer (score 5):

This works using Java 8's Base64 class:

```
public String getDecodedJwt(String jwt)
{
  String result = "";

  String[] parts = jwt.split("[.]");
  try
  {
    int index = 0;
    for(String part: parts)
    {
      if (index >= 2)
        break;

      index++;
      byte[] partAsBytes = part.getBytes("UTF-8");
      String decodedPart = new String(java.util.Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(partAsBytes), "UTF-8");

      result += decodedPart;
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    throw new RuntimeException("Couldnt decode jwt", e);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that is works only since API 26

Answer (score 3):

If the project is already using AWSCognito SDK then `CognitoJWTParser` class can be used.
It has static methods `getHeader()`, `getPayload()`, `getSignature()`.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/cognitoidentityprovider/util/CognitoJWTParser.java

Answer (score 2):

A no dependency version in Kotlin with Android SDK 26+ (Oreo):

```
fun extractJwt(jwt: String): String {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) return "Requires SDK 26"
    val parts = jwt.split(".")
    return try {
        val charset = charset("UTF-8")
        val header = String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(parts[0].toByteArray(charset)), charset)
        val payload = String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(parts[1].toByteArray(charset)), charset)
        "$header\n$payload"
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        "Error parsing JWT: $e"
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and I didn't have to import any libraries.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've used it in a Java web application and the code will look something like the below:-

```
Jwts.parser().setSigningKey('secret-key').parseClaimsJws(token).getBody()
```

It will return claims which contain the required values.

Answer (score 1):

this code convert `JWT` to `String` and work on any `API`

```
 public static String getDecodedJwt(String jwt)
   {
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

      String[] parts = jwt.split("[.]");
      try
      {
         int index = 0;
         for(String part: parts)
         {
            if (index >= 2)
               break;
            index++;
             byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(part.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.URL_SAFE);
            result.append(new String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8"));
         }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         throw new RuntimeException("Couldnt decode jwt", e);
      }

      return result.toString();
   }
```

Example :

```
JWTUtils.getDecodedJwt("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c")
```

And finally the resulting conversion

```
{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}{"sub":"1234567890","name":"John Doe","iat":1516239022}
```

Comment: Please, add imports.

Answer (score 0):

Based partially on the code provided by [Brad Parks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26510/brad-parks), adapted for use with lower versions of Android by using [Apache Commons](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec) and converted to Kotlin:

In `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'apache-codec:commons-codec:1.2'
```

In a Kotlin class:

```
fun decodeToken(token: String): String{
    val tokenParts: Array<String> = token.split(".").toTypedArray()
    if(tokenParts.isEmpty()) return token
    var decodedString = ""
    for(part: String in tokenParts){
        val partByteArray: ByteArray =
            stringToFullBase64EncodedLength(part).toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII)
        val decodedPart = String(Base64.decodeBase64(partByteArray))
        decodedString+=decodedPart
        // There are a maximum of two parts in an OAuth token,
        // and arrays are 0-indexed, so if the index is 1
        // we have processed the second part and should break.
        if(tokenParts.indexOf(part) == 1) break
    }
    return decodedString
}

private fun stringToFullBase64EncodedLength(string: String): String{

    // A properly base64 encoded string must be divisible by 4
    // We'll pad it to the nearest multiple of 4 without losing data:
    val targetLength: Int = ( 4 * ceil( string.length.toDouble()/4 ) ).toInt()

    // Now, we get the difference, and add it with a reserved character (`=`)
    // to the end of the string. It will get removed later.
    val requiredPadding: Int =  targetLength-string.length
    return string+"=".repeat(requiredPadding)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the library `io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts`, then use the following snippet. It works for me.

```
try {
        val claims: Claims =
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey.toByteArray()).parseClaimsJws(token).body
        return ConnectionClaim(claims["uid"].toString(), claims["key"].toString())

 } catch (e: JwtException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all forgot to add imports and select **android.util.Base64**!

```
import android.util.Base64
import org.json.JSONException

// Json data class
data class Data(
    val name: String?,
    val nonce: String?,
    // Other access_token fields
)

fun parseAccessToken(token: String): Data? {
    return try {
        val part = token.split(".")[1]
        val s = decodeJwt(part)
        // obj is an object of Gson or Moshi library
        obj.fromJson(s)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
}

@Throws(JSONException::class)
private fun decodeJwt(text: String): String {
    val s = Base64.decode(text, Base64.URL_SAFE)
    return String(s)
}
```