# jwt Signature exception while decoding

Tags: jwt

I am facing Signature exception while adding security to my Spring Rest services. Please help.

io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:354)

//Make Token

```
String token = Jwts.builder()
.setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes("UTF-8"))
.compact();
res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
```

// Decoding token

```
String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
if (token != null) {
// parse the token.

        String jwt = token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, "");
        try {
            Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(SECRET.getBytes("UTF-8"))
            .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
            .getBody();
            if (claims.getSubject() != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(claims.getSubject(), null, getAuthorities());
            }
        }
```

When I am printing both, I am getting the below text. One is having extra space. This is happening only when I am hitting the service using Rest client. Test classes are working fine.

makeToken= eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJza3AifQ.XUEsUFF3qm6fOeCG8xDLuRWjyd4kOh4g01olU_BsRyfqyI66MRhqmK-mxrAWsD17Ylmj-fZRRZUTRqxCQixxXQ

decodeToken=
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJza3AifQ.XUEsUFF3qm6fOeCG8xDLuRWjyd4kOh4g01olU_BsRyfqyI66MRhqmK-mxrAWsD17Ylmj-fZRR ZUTRqxCQixxXQ

Comment: Review the client code to remove the extra space from the header. The server code seems ok

Comment: I found out the issue, While taking the Bearer token from Rest Client(plugin in Mozilla) The next line is coming as an extra space.

Answer (score 1):

It's late but worth If someone is facing the same issue while decoding JWT token.

**Library GitHub link:**

> https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.Android

**Implementation:**

```
implementation ('com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:1.2.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

**Code:**

```
// token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbxxxxxxx9.eyJpZC*********************UEFUSUVOVCIsImV4cCI6MTU2NTY5MzU5MCwib3JpZ0lhdCI6MTU2NTA4ODc5MH0.ZhPpZSFZL6EY-Mwrw0F*********MYmbw

private void getExpDate(String token) {
    JWT jwt = new JWT(token);
    Log.e(TAG,"Claim - id:"+jwt.getClaim("id").asString()+" - username:"+jwt.getClaim("username").asString()+" - role:"+jwt.getClaim("role").asString()+" - exp:"+jwt.getClaim("exp").asString());
}
```

**Logcat Result:**

```
 E/PatientLogin: Claim - id:cd5dbe61-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx - username:xxxx@gmail.com - role:PATIENT - exp:1565693590
```

**Test JWT Token:**
If you want to check your JWT token then use below link.

> https://jwt.io/

**OR**

Here is another method which might work for you as well. This will help to avoid using a third-party library.

Reference: [Orignal post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751017/6672577)

```
decoded(token);

public static String decoded(String JWTEncoded) {
    String[] split = JWTEncoded.split("\\.");
    Log.e(TAG, "Header: " + getJson(split[0]));
    Log.e(TAG, "Body: " + getJson(split[1]));
    return getJson(split[1]);
}

private static String getJson(String strEncoded){
    String str_dec = "";
    try {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(strEncoded, Base64.URL_SAFE);
        str_dec = new String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str_dec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a bug in 0.9.x:

in EllipticCurveSignatureValidator.isValid():

```
            ...
            int expectedSize = EllipticCurveSignatureValidator.getSignatureByteArrayLength(this.alg);
            byte[] derSignature = expectedSize != signature.length && signature[0] == 48 ? signature : EllipticCurveProvider.transcodeSignatureToDER(signature);
```

The problem is that getSignatureByteArrayLength() returns a fixed length depending on the hash algo instead of the signature algo; so if you use a 384 bit key but a sha256 hash it will return 64 instead of 196.
And then if signature[0] is accidentally 0x30 = 48 (next line) it assumes the signature is DER encoded and tries to parse it -> error.

So the bug can occur (about 1 time in 256) for EC signature when the key size differs from the hash size.