# retrieve the id on the encrypted hash response

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, httpresponse

retrieve the id on the encrypted hash response. Can it be decrypted on the Java Android function?

which appears when the toast is a result string, I can't get the id, when I take the username string, what appears is the string result. Help and im confused

Json Response

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "reason": "OK",
    "success": true,
    "message": null,
    "result": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiJ9.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.zIEhdU5MyNjReG_9_661FWf0_R5eZuJweyl0JNFd7X0"
}
```

LoginUser.java

```
    public void LoginUser() {
        //membuat progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMessage("Tunggu proses login ...");
        pDialog.show();

        //mengambil data dari edittext

        final String username = txtusername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = txtpassword.getText().toString().trim();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL).client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson())).build();

        RequestInterface api = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<ResponseLoginSucces> call = api.login_member(username,  password);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseLoginSucces>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseLoginSucces> call, Response<ResponseLoginSucces> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    if(response.body().getResult() != null){

                        // Jika login berhasil
                        String id = response.body().getResult();
                        String email = response.body().getResult();
                        String username = response.body().getResult();
                        String msisdn = response.body().getResult();
                        sharedPrefManager.saveSPString(SharedPrefManager.SP_ID, id);
                        sharedPrefManager.saveSPString(SharedPrefManager.SP_EMAIL, email);
                        sharedPrefManager.saveSPString(SharedPrefManager.SP_USERNAME, username);
                        sharedPrefManager.saveSPString(SharedPrefManager.SP_MSISDN, msisdn);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil Login" +id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginUser.this, MenuUtama.class);
                        sharedPrefManager.saveSPBoolean(SharedPrefManager.SP_SUDAH_LOGIN, true);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();


                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginUser.this, "The username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginUser.this, "Error! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseLoginSucces> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LoginUser.this, "Koneksi internet terputus.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



    }
```

SharedPrefManager.java

```
public class SharedPrefManager {

    public static final String SP_Kreditimpian = "kreditimpian_v2_demo";

    public static final String SP_ID = "id";
    public static final String SP_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String SP_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String SP_MSISDN ="msisdn";

    public static final String SP_SUDAH_LOGIN = "spSudahLogin";

    SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;

    public SharedPrefManager(Context context){
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_Kreditimpian, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        spEditor = sp.edit();
    }

    public void saveSPString(String keySP, String value){
        spEditor.putString(keySP, value);
        spEditor.commit();
    }

    public void saveSPInt(String keySP, int value){
        spEditor.putInt(keySP, value);
        spEditor.commit();
    }

    public void saveSPBoolean(String keySP, boolean value){
        spEditor.putBoolean(keySP, value);
        spEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getSPID(){
        return sp.getString(SP_ID, "");
    }

    public String getSPEmail(){
        return sp.getString(SP_EMAIL, "");
    }

    public String getSpUsername(){
        return sp.getString(SP_USERNAME, "");
    }

    public String getSpMsisdn(){
        return sp.getString(SP_MSISDN, "");
    }

    public Boolean getSPSudahLogin(){
        return sp.getBoolean(SP_SUDAH_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

FragmentMenu.java

```
sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(getActivity());

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Identitas mu "+ sharedPrefManager.getSPID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Android development, but if you know the algorithm and key for encryption, then you can decrypt it as well.

Comment: How did you generate that hash code in the first place?

Comment: I do not understand how the hash started. I get an API from the Vendor and the results of the login validation get the results like encrypting it. when I ask, the code is generated from String ID, USERNAME, EMAIL, PHONE. they don't explain what method to use the hash. Can you explain the problem above?

Comment: I do not understand how the hash started. I get an API from the Vendor and the results of the login validation get the results like encrypting it. when I ask, the code is generated from String ID, USERNAME, EMAIL, PHONE. they don't explain what method to use the hash. Can you explain the problem above?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you're asking, but the `result` in that JSON is Base64 encoded (most of it, anyway).

Comment: yes like that, can you help me to solve this problem? this case I want to retrieve the String member ID for me to save in sharedpreferences

Comment: OK, apparently it's specifically a JSON Web Token, which consists of three Base64 encoded sections with periods (`.`) separating them. The data you want is in the middle section, methinks. I've never dealt with these before, but it looks to be pretty straightforward string splitting and Base64 decoding. The answers on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37695877) might be of some help to you. There are surely other posts here, too, if ya dig around.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I think this is what I'm looking for. thank you for the answer. I'll try first

Answer (score 0):

As @Mike M. said above, the `result` in response JSON string seems to be encoded with Base64 and it can be viewed as 3 parts separated by dot(.). So if you decode the 2nd part you will get following valid JSON string, then the value `499` of field `id` is what you want to retrieve.

```
{ 
  "id":"499",
  "email":"bismillahbisa@example.com",
  "msisdn":"079797846494",
  "username":"bismillahbisa",
  "verifiedMember":null,
  "profile":{ 
    "id":"316",
    "id_geodirectory":null,
    "fullname":"bismillahbisa",
    "number":"274247",
    "image":"https:\/\/demo.kreditimpian.com\/storage\/images\/default\/avatar.jpg",
    "record":{ 
      "status":"PUBLISH",
      "create":{ 
        "user":null,
        "timestamp":{ 
          "date":"2019-12-03 15:08:32.000000",
          "timezone_type":3,
          "timezone":"Asia\/Jakarta"
        }
      },
      "update":{ 
        "user":null,
        "timestamp":null
      }
    },
    "metadata":{ 
      "username":"bismillahbisa",
      "email":"bismillahbisa@example.com",
      "phone":"079797846494"
    },
    "statistic":null
  }
}
```

If you can get `result` in response first, then you can use following code snippet to decode the 2nd part of `result` with `java.util.Base64`(Java 8). For Java 7, you can use `Apache Commons Codec` for decoding (Maven dependency shows below). And finally, retrieve the value of `id` with 3 of the most popular JSON libraries - `Jackson`, `Gson` and `org.json`.

**Apache Commons Codec (for Java 7)**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code snippet**

```
// Java 8
//String jsonStr = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(resultStr.split("\\.")[1].getBytes()), "UTF-8");

// Java 7
String jsonStr = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(result.split("\\.")[1]), "UTF-8");

// Jackson
String id = new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonStr).get("id").asText();

// Gson
id = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, JsonObject.class).get("id").getAsString();

// org.json
id = new JSONObject(jsonStr).getString("id");
```

Comment: "resultStr.split"   where did you get it from?

Comment: @indriyanto Nugroho ‵resultStr equals `response.body().getResult()` if its output is the value of `result` in response JSON string.

Comment: Can I put it after the response function ??? as follows @LHCHIN

Comment: @indriyanto Nugroho Sure, you can! And could you post what your IDE says about the error in above URL?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q6c4w3 this error,
I don't know what mistakes, do I need to add dependencies for Base64? if so, which dependency? @LHCHIN

Comment: @indriyanto Nugroho It seems that your JDK version is smaller than 8 because `java.util.Base64` is introduced since Java 8. I have added the solution for Java 7, please check it out! Or you can change your SDK level to 26 if possible.

Comment: @indriyanto Nugroho Sorry, I am not familiar with Android development, but can you modify the `minSdkVersion` to be 26 to use `java.util.Base64`. Or you have to add dependency of `Apache Commons Codec` first as I mentioned above.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q6e0ky After I tried switching to SDK 26, it was successful, but the string itself wasn't readable. thank you at least you helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void LoginUser() {
        //membuat progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMessage("Tunggu proses login ...");
        pDialog.show();

        //mengambil data dari edittext

        final String username = txtusername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = txtpassword.getText().toString().trim();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL).client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson())).build();

        RequestInterface api = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<ResponseLoginSucces> call = api.login_member(username,  password);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseLoginSucces>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseLoginSucces> call, Response<ResponseLoginSucces> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    if(response.body().getResult() != null){

                        String jsonStr = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(resultStr.split("\\.")[1].getBytes()), "UTF-8");
                        // Gson
                        id = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, JsonObject.class).get("id").getAsString();





                        // Jika login berhasil
                        String id = response.body().getResult();
                        String email = response.body().getResult();
                        String username = response.body().getResult();
                        String msisdn = response.body().getResult();
                        sharedPrefManager.saveSPString(SharedPrefManager.SP_ID, id);
                        sharedPrefManager.saveSPString(SharedPrefManager.SP_EMAIL, email);
                        sharedPrefManager.saveSPString(SharedPrefManager.SP_USERNAME, username);
                        sharedPrefManager.saveSPString(SharedPrefManager.SP_MSISDN, msisdn);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil Login" +id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginUser.this, MenuUtama.class);
                        sharedPrefManager.saveSPBoolean(SharedPrefManager.SP_SUDAH_LOGIN, true);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();



                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginUser.this, "The username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginUser.this, "Error! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseLoginSucces> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LoginUser.this, "Koneksi internet terputus.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



    }
```