# Decode Token JWT android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, jwt, key, token

I have a token like this:

```
hereeyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJvcGVyYWRvciI6eyJpZCI6NzAsIm5vbWUiOiJERUlWSVRJIiwidXN1YXJpbyI6IkRFSVZJVEkifSwiaWF0IjoxNjI5ODEyNDA1fQ.JqzQnFSbG6gFsnlJu3-bezxZ_N5e5FEzc9QvpRGu0u4
```

hide it:

```
 alg: "HS256",
 typ: "JWT"
}.

 operador: {
  id: 20,
  nome: "JOAO",
  usuario: "JOAO"
 },
 iat: 1629812405
}
```

Question is how do I get on android kotlin only user id to use in certain tasks?

Answer (score 6):

I just fix the issue thanks to this:

```
private fun decodeToken(jwt: String): String {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) return "Requires SDK 26"
    val parts = jwt.split(".")
    return try {
        val charset = charset("UTF-8")
        val header = String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(parts[0].toByteArray(charset)), charset)
        val payload = String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(parts[1].toByteArray(charset)), charset)
        "$header"
        "$payload"
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        "Error parsing JWT: $e"
    }
}
```

Then :

```
val mDecode = decodeToken(mToken)
val test = JSONObject(mDecode).getString("operador")
val mDecodeTokenOk = JSONObject(test).getString("id")
/** SALVANDO ID_OPERADOR */
mSharedPreferences.saveString(WmsConstantes.ID_OPERADOR,mDecodeTokenOk)
Log.e("------------------>", mDecodeTokenOk.toString());
```

Comment: Some of jwts doesn't have "." , you can use this jwt.replace("}{", "}.{")

Answer (score 3):

You could use this,

https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.Android

Assuming the `iat` value is the user id,

```
var jwt: JWT = JWT(YOUR_TOKEN_STRING)
var claim: Claim = jwt.getClaim("iat")
//or as a string
var claim: String = jwt.getClaim("iat").asString()
```

Comment: I understand, in this case I need to use the "ID" that is inside the "OPERATOR" of the token

Comment: `iat` stands for "issued at", it's the timestamp of when was the token issued. You need the `operador` claim, and the `id` field from that claim.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to install any libraries. You can try something like this.

- Class(s) reflecting your `JWT` payload

```
data class JwtPayload(

    @SerializedName("iat")
    val iat: Int,

    @SerializedName("operador")
    val operador: Operador
)

data class Operador(

    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,

    @SerializedName("nome")
    val nome: String,

    @SerializedName("usuario")
    val usuario: String
)
```

- You can use this class as a wrapper for your token

```
class Jwt(private val token: String) {

    private val userData: JsonObject by lazy {
        val userData = String(Base64.decode(token.split(".")[1], Base64.DEFAULT), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        JsonParser.parseString(userData).asJsonObject
    }

    fun getUserData(): JwtPayload{
        gson.toJson(userData, Jwt::class.java)
        return gson.fromJson(userData, JwtPayload::class.java)
    }

    fun isExpired(): Boolean {
        return userData.asJsonObject.get("exp").asLong < (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
    }

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        private val gson = Gson()
    }
}
```

- Usage

```
val token = Jwt("YOUR_TOKEN")
val operatorID = token.operator.id
```

Comment: This solution requires Gson, which is a library, no? 

Comment: @SvenJacobs Haha What I meant was without using any additional libraries. Anyone can swap GSON with anything they want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Parsing method to any class

```
        @JvmStatic
        private val gsonRef = Gson()
        @JvmStatic
        private val parserRef = JsonParser()

        fun Parse(token: String) : DecodedLoginToken {
            val delimittedData = String(Base64.decode(token.split(".")[1], Base64.DEFAULT), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            val result = gsonRef.fromJson(delimittedData, DecodedLoginToken::class.java)
            return result
        }
```